# Azure DevOps - Dropdown list of Project names dynamically load from organization level

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

For Azure DevOps pipeline, is it possible to load all the project names as dropdown list before running the pipeline? The requirement that i am working on is to import some GitLab repo to Azure DevOps. The import process is working fine and now the number of projects is increasing day by day. As of now I'm editing the yml script and adding the project names manually to show the project names to the users.

So for below, if I wish to have the same dropdown of Project names (values) that will be pulled from the organization level so that users can select from the same to import the GitLab repo.

```
parameters:
  - name: ProjectName
    displayName: Select the Project
    type: string
    default: Project1
    values:
    - Project1
    - Project2
    - Project3
    - Project4
    - Project5
  - name: GitlabRepoUrl
    type: string
    displayName: 'Enter Gitlab Repository Url that you want to Import'
```

Comment: We've been looking for this for a while now, but never found a solution. I'll follow this question